# Why ICollection<Post> does not implement IEnumerable<IPost>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a blog, so each post has some topic and vise versa (a many-to-many relationship). I've created two `Interface`s and two `Class`es, and I want to create database using `EF Code First` solution. this is my code:

```
// interfaces

public interface IPost
{
    int id { get; set; }

    string name { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<ITopic> topics { get; set; }
}

public interface ITopic
{
    int id { get; set; }

    string name { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<IPost> posts { get; set; }
}

// classes

public class Post : IPost
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    // ... (other properties)

    public virtual ICollection<Topic> topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topic : ITopic
{
    int id { get; set; }

    string name { get; set; }

    // ... (other properties)

    public virtual ICollection<Post> posts { get; set; }
}
```

But I get the following error:

`'Topic' does not implement interface member 'ITopic.posts'. 'Topic.posts' cannot implement 'ITopic.posts' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerable<IPost>'.`

And also, I get the (almost) same error for `Post`.

I know that `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` interface. and, as you see, `Post` implements `IPost`. So, why i get this error? I tried these also (whitin `Topic` class):

1- `public virtual ICollection<IPost> posts { get; set; }`

2- `public virtual IEnumerable<Post> posts { get; set; }` (why this one dose not work?!)

The only code that works is `public virtual IEnumerable<IPost> posts { get; set; }`, but then I will lose the other propertis of a `Post` when enumerating `topic.posts`. worse, I can't create database using `EF Code First` solution.

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: Simply, `ICollection<T>` is invariant for `T`. In other words, it doesn't allow subtyping of the generic argument.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` is an invariant interface, because `T` is used for parameter types as well as for return types. Thatswhy a `ICollection<Post>` is a _different_ type (no inheritance or what so ever) than `ICollection<IPost>`. You could declare both properties (and the one from `ITopic` as `virtual ITopic.ICollection<IPost> posts {get;set;}` but that would mean to have two separate collections you'd need to synchronize. Don't see a good work around at first glance... maybe having interfaces is not _so_ necessary and you could live with class declarations only?

Comment: why my trying #2 not working?!

Comment: It does not work because the compiler thinks this should be the implementation of the interface's `posts` property, but the type does not match.

Comment: so now what shoud i do? trying to get rid of interfaces?!

Comment: Why do you need the Interfaces? In my understanding, you are using the interfaces only one time. If this is correct, the interfaces are totally unnecessary.

Comment: no, i want to use interfaces within my services and repositories.

Comment: But this causes a lot of problems here. As I said above you _could_ declare both properties (by hiding the interface implementation), but then you have the problem that the getters would return two different collection instances (they can't return the _same_ instance because of type mismatch), so there could be some behaviour not expected by consumers of your class.